# How to slide indicator image on a semi circle Path

Tags: android

i have created a custom view in that view i draw arc but i want to slide indicator on that arc with same

Path path = new Path();

```
  path.addArc(oval,180,180);
```

in onDraw method and i want to slide image on this particular path

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I13S4.png

public SemiCircle(Context context) {
        super(context);

}

public SemiCircle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {

super(context, attrs);

```
  init(context, attrs);
```

}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

// Defaults, may need to link this into theme settings

int arcColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_arc);

```
  int progressColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_progress);




 int textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_text);
```

mProgressWidth = (int) (mProgressWidth * density);

mArcWidth = (int) (mArcWidth * density);

mTextSize = (int) (mTextSize * density);

mIndicatorIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.pointer);

if (attrs != null) {

```
 // Attribute initialization




   final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SwagPoints, 0, 0);
```

Drawable indicatorIcon =

a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SwagPoints_indicatorIcon);

if (indicatorIcon != null)
                mIndicatorIcon = indicatorIcon;

int indicatorIconHalfWidth = mIndicatorIcon.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;

int indicatorIconHalfHeight = mIndicatorIcon.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
            mIndicatorIcon.setBounds(-indicatorIconHalfWidth, -

indicatorIconHalfHeight, indicatorIconHalfWidth,
                    indicatorIconHalfHeight);

mPoints = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SwagPoints_points, mPoints);

mMin = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SwagPoints_min, mMin);

```
mMax = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SwagPoints_max, mMax);




mStep = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SwagPoints_step, mStep);







mProgressWidth = (int)
```

a.getDimension(R.styleable.SwagPoints_progressWidth, mProgressWidth);

```
    progressColor =
```

a.getColor(R.styleable.SwagPoints_progressColor, progressColor);

```
   mArcWidth = (int)
```

a.getDimension(R.styleable.SwagPoints_arcWidth, mArcWidth);

```
arcColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SwagPoints_arcColor, arcColor);





 mTextSize = (int)
```

a.getDimension(R.styleable.SwagPoints_textSize, mTextSize);

```
   textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SwagPoints_textColor, textColor);
```

mClockwise = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SwagPoints_clockwise,
                    mClockwise);

mEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SwagPoints_enabled, mEnabled);

a.recycle();

```
 }




  // range check
```

mPoints = (mPoints > mMax) ? mMax : mPoints;

mPoints = (mPoints < mMin) ? mMin : mPoints;

mProgressSweep = (float) mPoints / valuePerDegree();

mArcPaint = new Paint();

mArcPaint.setColor(arcColor);

```
mArcPaint.setAntiAlias(true);


mArcPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);



 mArcPaint.setStrokeWidth(mArcWidth);
```

mProgressPaint = new Paint();

mProgressPaint.setColor(progressColor);

```
mProgressPaint.setAntiAlias(true);



mProgressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

mProgressPaint.setStrokeWidth(mProgressWidth);

```
mTickPaint = new Paint();



mTickPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);



mTickPaint.setStrokeWidth(TICK_THICKNESS);



mTickPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);




mTextPaint = new Paint();



mTextPaint.setColor(textColor);



 mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);




mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);

}

private float valuePerDegree() {

```
 return (float) (mMax) / 360.0f;
```

}

@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)

{

width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

final int min = Math.min(width, height);

/*   if (width > height) {

```
    radius = height / 4;



 } else {



      radius = width / 4;
```

}

*/

mTranslateX = (int) (width /2);

mTranslateY = (int) (height );

int arcDiameter = min - getPaddingLeft();

radius = arcDiameter/2;

center_x = width /2;

center_y = height ;

oval.set(center_x - radius,

```
center_y - radius,
```

center_x + radius,

```
center_y + radius);







updateIndicatorIconPosition();
```

super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}

@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
```

if (!mClockwise) {

```
  canvas.scale(-1, 1, oval.centerX(), oval.centerY());
```

}

```
 String textPoint = String.valueOf(mPoints);
```

mTextPaint.getTextBounds(textPoint, 0, textPoint.length(), mTextRect);

// center the text

int xPos = canvas.getWidth() /2 - mTextRect.width() ;

int yPos = (int) ((oval.centerY()) - ((mTextPaint.descent() +

mTextPaint.ascent()) ));

//      Log.d("onDraw", String.valueOf(mPoints));

```
   canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(mPoints), xPos, 150, mTextPaint);




  Path path = new Path();




 path.addArc(oval,180,180);
```

// canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, 180, false, mArcPaint);

ScNotches scNotches = new ScNotches(path);

scNotches.getPainter().setStrokeWidth(9);

scNotches.setColors( Color.RED);

scNotches.setCount(60);

scNotches.setLength(180);

scNotches.draw(canvas);

ScNotches scNotchess = new ScNotches(path);

scNotchess.getPainter().setStrokeWidth(9);

scNotchess.setColors( Color.RED);

scNotchess.setCount(1);

scNotchess.setLength(180);

if (mEnabled) {

// draw the indicator icon

canvas.translate(mTranslateX - mIndicatorIconX, mTranslateY -

mIndicatorIconY);

```
  mIndicatorIcon.draw(canvas);



 }
```

}

@Override

protected void drawableStateChanged() {

```
  super.drawableStateChanged();




  if (mIndicatorIcon != null && mIndicatorIcon.isStateful()) {




    int[] state = getDrawableState();




   mIndicatorIcon.setState(state);
```

}

invalidate();

}

private void updateIndicatorIconPosition() {

int thumbAngle = (int) (mProgressSweep + 327);

mIndicatorIconX = (int) (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));

mIndicatorIconY = (int) (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));

}

public void setPoints(int points) {

points = points > mMax ? mMax : points;

points = points < mMin ? mMin : points;

updateProgress(points, false);

}

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

if (mEnabled) {

```
   // 阻止父View去攔截onTouchEvent()事件，確保touch事件可以正確傳遞到此層View
```

。

this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

switch (event.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

```
   if (mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null)
```

mOnSwagPointsChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);

//

```
        updateOnTouch(event);





    break;
```

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

```
 updateOnTouch(event);




 break;
```

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

if (mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null)

mOnSwagPointsChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);

```
            setPressed(false);
```

this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

```
       break;




  case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:






      if (mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null)
```

mOnSwagPointsChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);

```
      setPressed(false);
```

this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

```
       break;



    }
```

return true;

```
  }
```

return false;

}

/**
     * Update all the UI components on touch events.
     *
     * @param event MotionEvent
     */

private void updateOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {

```
setPressed(true);
```

mTouchAngle = convertTouchEventPointToAngle(event.getX(),

event.getY());

int progress = convertAngleToProgress(mTouchAngle);

updateProgress(progress, true);

}

private double convertTouchEventPointToAngle(float xPos, float yPos) {

// transform touch coordinate into component coordinate

float x = xPos - mTranslateX;

float y = yPos - mTranslateY;

x = (mClockwise) ? x : -x;

double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x) + (Math.PI / 2));

angle = (angle < 0) ? (angle + 360) : angle;

//      System.out.printf("(%f, %f) %f\n", x, y, angle);

```
return angle;
```

}

private int convertAngleToProgress(double angle) {

```
return (int) Math.round(valuePerDegree() * angle);
```

}

private void updateProgress(int progress, boolean fromUser) {

// detect points change closed to max or min

final int maxDetectValue = (int) ((double) mMax * 0.95);

final int minDetectValue = (int) ((double) mMax * 0.05) + mMin;

//      System.out.printf("(%d, %d) / (%d, %d)\n", mMax, mMin,

maxDetectValue, minDetectValue);

```
 mUpdateTimes++;
```

if (progress == INVALID_VALUE) {

```
   return;
```

}

// avoid accidentally touch to become max from original point

// 避免在靠近原點點到直接變成最大值

if (progress > maxDetectValue && mPreviousProgress == INVALID_VALUE) {

//          System.out.printf("Skip (%d) %.0f -> %.0f %s\n",

//progress, mPreviousProgress, mCurrentProgress, isMax ?

"Max" : "");

return;

}

```
    // record previous and current progress change
```

// 紀錄目前和前一個進度變化

if (mUpdateTimes == 1) {

```
  mCurrentProgress = progress;
```

} else {

```
 mPreviousProgress = mCurrentProgress;






 mCurrentProgress = progress;
```

}

//      if (mPreviousProgress != mCurrentProgress)

//          System.out.printf("Progress (%d)(%f) %.0f -> %.0f (%s, %s)\n",

//                  progress, mTouchAngle,

//                  mPreviousProgress, mCurrentProgress,

//                  isMax ? "Max" : "",

//                  isMin ? "Min" : "");

// 不能直接拿progress來做step

mPoints = progress - (progress % mStep);

/

**
         * Determine whether reach max or min to lock point update event.
         *
         * When reaching max, the progress will drop from max (or maxDetectPoints ~ max
         * to min (or min ~ minDetectPoints) and vice versa.
         *
         * If reach max or min, stop increasing / decreasing to avoid exceeding the max / min.
         */
        // 判斷超過最大值或最小值，最大最小值不重複判斷
        // 用數值範圍判斷預防轉太快直接略過最大最小值。
        // progress變化可能從98 -> 0/1 or 0/1 -> 98/97，而不會過0或100

if (mUpdateTimes > 1 && !isMin && !isMax) {

```
     if (mPreviousProgress >= maxDetectValue && mCurrentProgress <= minDetectValue &&






       mPreviousProgress > mCurrentProgress) {





isMax = true;
```

progress = mMax;

mPoints = mMax;

//              System.out.println("Reach Max " + progress);

if (mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null) {

mOnSwagPointsChangeListener                          .onPointsChanged(this, progress, fromUser);

```
  return;
```

}

} else if ((mCurrentProgress >= maxDetectValue

```
&& mPreviousProgress <= minDetectValue
```

&& mCurrentProgress > mPreviousProgress) || mCurrentProgress <= mMin) {

isMin = true;

progress = mMin;

mPoints = mMin;

//              Log.d("Reach", "Reach Min " + progress);

```
if (mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null) {





 mOnSwagPointsChangeListener

              .onPointsChanged(this, progress, fromUser);




    return;
            }



     }
```

invalidate();

} else {

// Detect whether decreasing from max or increasing from min, to unlock the update event.

// Make sure to check in detect range only.

if (isMax & (mCurrentProgress < mPreviousProgress) && mCurrentProgress >= maxDetectValue) {

//              System.out.println("Unlock max");

```
       isMax = false;

  }
```

if (isMin

```
     && (mPreviousProgress < mCurrentProgress)





&& mPreviousProgress <= minDetectValue && mCurrentProgress <= minDetectValue
```

&& mPoints >= mMin) {

//              Log.d("Unlock", String.format("Unlock min %.0f, %.0f\n", mPreviousProgress, mCurrentProgress));

```
      isMin = false;
```

}

}

if (!isMax && !isMin) {

progress = (progress > mMax) ? mMax : progress;

progress = (progress < mMin) ? mMin : progress;

if

(mOnSwagPointsChangeListener != null) {

progress = progress - (progress % mStep);

mOnSwagPointsChangeListener

.onPointsChanged(this, progress, fromUser);

}

mProgressSweep = (float) progress / valuePerDegree();

//          if (mPreviousProgress != mCurrentProgress)

//              System.out.printf("-- %d, %d, %f\n", progress, mPoints,

```
    mProgressSweep);
```

updateIndicatorIconPosition();

invalidate();

}

}

Comment: Please post additional code that you've tried to achieve this effect

Comment: ok i will post my class

Comment: I have done this issue now its working fine . i have created a library for the same cheers.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer mentioning relevant links and details. It helps the community grow. Cheers!

Comment: Please check my git url https://github.com/call5saket/Temperature_Increase_Guage